# use last successful execution time in lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda function that I use to fetch data from an API. In my lambda function, I use current time - 1 hour. Instead of this, I want to use current time - [last successful execution time] for that function. Is that possible?

```
    from_time = ""
    if response["executions"]:
        start_time = response["executions"][0]["startDate"]
        week_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
        week_ago = week_ago.replace(tzinfo=start_time.tzinfo)
        if start_time > week_ago:
            from_time = get_utc_time(start_time)
        else:
            from_time = get_utc_time(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1))
        logger.info(f"Last successful execution time in UTC: {from_time}")
```

I came across this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/get-execution-history.html

but I don't understand how I can use this `get-execution-history` in my case (terraformed lambda function inside a step function)

Comment: maye you could save value in file and read it in next execution.

Comment: how to get, save and read? that's the question :P @furas

Comment: use the AWS SDK Step Function Class and methods for it, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html

but yes, I would say you should store the execution reference, or the time somewhere

Answer (score 1):

use your SDK, in pythons case Boto3

```
 import boto3

 state_machine_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
 execution_data = state_machine_client.describe_execution(executionArn="execution arn")

 if execution_data.get('status') == "SUCCEEDED":
      end_time = execution_data.get('stopDate')
```

for pretty much all interaction between AWS services use the SDK of your lanuage (Boto3 for python)

You can read more here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.describe_execution

If you don't know the execution arn, you can find it with https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.list_executions and the first item in the list ***i believe*** is the last one. Im pretty sure that is how it orders it automatically. - and that has the start and stop time as well.